# How to use Google Login API to sign into WebView on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, android-webview, google-plus

Since there is a Login API from Google for Android, I would like to make it that when Google websites are accessed in my WebView, users are already logged in from their Google accounts saved on their phone. How would I go about this? Thank you!